# MySQL Query for getting Payments & Invoices in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, union

A customer has asked me to pull some extra accounting data for their statements. I have been having trouble writing a query that can accomodate this.

What they initially wanted was to get all **"payments"** from a certain date range that belongs to a certain account, ordered as oldest first, which was a simple statement as follows

```
SELECT * FROM `payments` 
WHERE `sales_invoice_id` = ? 
ORDER_BY `created_at` ASC;
```

However, now they want to have newly raised **"invoices"** as part of the statement. I cannot seem to write the correct query for this. Union does not seem to work, and JOINS behave like, well, joins, so that I cannot get a seperate row for each payment/invoice; it instead **merges them together**. Ideally, I would retrieve a set of results as follows:

```
payment.amount | invoice.amount | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------
NULL           | 250.00         | 2014-02-28 8:00:00
120.00         | NULL           | 2014-02-28 8:00:00
```

This way I can loop through these to generate a full statement. The latest query I tried was the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `payments` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sales_invoices` 
ON `payments`.`account_id` = `sales_invoices`.`account_id` 
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC;
```

The first problem would be that the **"created_at"** column is ambiguous, so I am not sure how to merge these. The second problem is that it merges rows and brings back duplicate rows which is incorrect.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way or is there a feature of MySQL I am not aware of that can do this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` for this.  You just need to define the columns carefully:

```
select ip.*
from ((select p.invoice_id, p.amount as payment, NULL as invoice, p.created_at
       from payments p
      ) union all
      (select i.invoice_id, NULL, i.amount, i.created_at
       from sales_invoices i
      )
     ) ip
order by created_at asc;
```

Your question is specifically about MySQL.  Other databases support a type of join called the `full outer join`, which can also be used for this type of query (MySQL does not support `full outer join`).

Comment: So far this works fantastically, thank you. I believe my issue was a misunderstanding of how union works. A new issue has arisen, when I try add a **where payments.account_id = ?** clause after from payments p it gives me a **Unknown column 'payments.customer_id' in 'where clause'** SQL error. Even if I try to use **p.account_id** isntead of **payments.accounts_id** it still cannot find the column name. How would I go about this?

Comment: @SixteenStudio . . . The query uses table aliases to make the query more readable.  A table alias is an abbreviation for the table name. Use `p.account_id` in the first subquery.  Otherwise, just include `account_id` in both subqueries, and use `where account_id = ?` in the outer query.

Comment: I see that I did not include the correct column name in the subquery. Perfect!